# Query to find nearest road highway tag to a (latitude,longitude) point

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, layers, osm2pgsql

I imported an OSM file for the state of Delaware into the PostGIS Database via connecting to it through QGIS. I would like to build a query to retrieve the nearest roads to the (latitude,longitude) points I have.

When I imported to QGIS, it created 4 layers: one for linestring, one for points, one for multilinestrings, a and once for multi polygons. I believe the only ones I need would be lines. So far I have imported my table of 1000 ( latitude, longitude) points. I need to write a query that for each point, will return the highway tag of the nearest road to that point. I've written a query that casts each latitude longitude into a point geometry:

```
select ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(end_latitude::float, end_longitude::float)
from gis.delaware_trip_slices
```

Each row output here would be for example Point(37.2,75.32) etc.
Now, I just have to find a way to return the highway tag for the nearest road to each of these points. Do you have any pointers how I would go about doing this.

I saw a query like this online, but I don't know what this means:

```
Select *
From towns 
order by the_geom <->
SETSRID(ST_Make_Point(lat,long),4236) 
Limit 5
```

My guess is somehow I could make the above query a temporary table. Then I would for each value in the temporary table search for the nearest road.  Does anyone have any pointers

Comment: You'll find all relevant information about the concept needed and its implementation in e.g. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401429/93656) answer and its links, and/or via the tag [tag:knn] on GIS.SE

Comment: 1) see the [operator doc](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html), 2) coordinates should be in the longitude;latitude format, 3) [beware](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375981/postgis-combine-st-distancesphere-with-nearest-neighbor-search/375985#375985) that `<->` uses the Cartesian distance, which is meaningless with geometries in 4236

Answer (score 1):

`<->` operator tells the distance between two geometries. Sorting tables using this operator is very fast if there is a spatial index created on the tables.

The following query selects one point at a time and then finds the nearest road for it. You didn't specify the schema of your tables so you have to fix all the column names etc.

```sql
SELECT
  points.name,
  roads.name,
  roads.dist
FROM
  gis.delaware_trip_slices points
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT osm_lines.name, osm_lines.geom <-> ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(end_latitude::float, end_longitude::float), 4326)), 3857) AS dist
    FROM osm_lines
    WHERE osm_lines.tag = 'highway'
    ORDER BY dist
    LIMIT 1
  ) roads
```

Comment: I used <-> in the ORDER BY statement is that ok?

Comment: The last part of the query is like: CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT hlines.id, 
 osm_lines.line_geometry, 
 osm_lines.highway,
 osm_lines.geom_text
    FROM osm_lines
    ORDER BY osm_lines.line_geometry <-> hpoints.point_geometry 
    LIMIT 1